# Wiring wsclient Webservices in resources.groovy

Tags: spring, grails

I have a situation where I need to be able to shovel data down in three classic environments:  dev, itg, and CAT.  I have working code in my webservice controller, but am now factoring that logic out to its own service for two reasons.  First, to separate concerns, second to better performance.  Keeping the webservice initialization in a controller means that the transformation from wsdl to groovy object is repeated every time the controller is invoked--not ideal.

However I keep getting initialization errors when attempting to wire these together.

```
spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator [RuntimeConfiguration] Unable to load beans from resources.groovy
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static org.grails.plugins.wsclient.service.WebService.getClient() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [WSDL-LOCATION-HERE]
Possible solutions: getClient(java.lang.String), getClient(java.lang.String, groovyx.net.ws.cxf.SoapVersion), getClass(), getAt(java.lang.String)
```

The offending code is:

```
// Place your Spring DSL code here
import org.grails.plugins.wsclient.service.WebService;
beans = {

    itgFilenetService(testbed.webservices.FileNetService) { 
        wsdlLocation = "WSDL-LOCATION-HERE"
        webService = WebService.getClient(wsdlLocation)
    }

//  FileNetController(testbed.webservices){
//      fileNet = itgFilenetService
//  }

}
```

I get the idea that I'm doing something really wrong here, because clearly... `WebService.getClient(String)` is and has been a legal constructor for ages... what am I missing?

I attempted a suggestion here, doing:

```
def ib = [

    afterPropertiesSet:{
        itgWebService = WebService.getClient("WSDL")
        catWebService = WebService.getClient("WSDL")
        }

    ] as InitializingBean
```

But this code was never invoked at runtime.
I realize (now) that one big problem was treating the Webservice.getClient() as a static call.  I hadn't done it before, but well... learn by doing...
SOLVED Below:

Answer (score 0):

Two options to solve your issue.

First, try implementing [InitializingBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.html) on your service and move your code into afterPropertiesSet(). I suspect this will resolve your issue and offer you a cleaner implementation as well.

However, if for some reason that does NOT work (maybe somehow the resources for that plugin aren't available, all though they should be by then), you can always move your code into Bootstrap.groovy.

I would recommend trying the first option.

Comment: Can you give a little more detail?  I tried to go down the path of using the interface, writing 

` def ib = [
   
  afterPropertiesSet:{
   itgWebService = WebService.getClient("WSDL")
   catWebService = WebService.getClient(WSDL
   }
  
  ] as InitializingBean`

and this code was never invoked.  I'm staying away from the boostrap right now...

Comment: Your code should look something like this:
class MyService implements InitalizingBean {
 void afterPropertiesSet() {
  // whatever needs to be done in here.
 }
}

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation on the ws-client plugin (http://www.grails.org/plugin/ws-client), .getClient(String) is not a static method, so you need to invoke it on a `WebService`object, not the class.  That's where the MME is coming from.

If you want to do this in resources.groovy, try using the `MethodInvokingFactoryBean` from Spring:

```
webService(org.grails.plugins.wsclient.service.WebService)

parsedWsdlWSClient(org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean) {
    targetObject = ref('webService')
    targetMethod = 'getClient'
    arguments = ["WSDL-LOCATION-HERE"]
}

itgFilenetService(testbed.webservices.FileNetService) { 
    webService = ref('parsedWsdlWSClient')
}
```

Note, then, that `itgFilenetService.webService` will be an instance of `WSClient`, not `WebService`.

Or, if you want to take advantage of Grails autowiring, you could add `def parsedWsdlWSClient` to the Grails Service that needs it and skip the assignment step in resources.groovy.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Not at all the "grails-y" way to do it, but since I couldn't get autowiring to work--even after realizing the mistake of a static call--I NEEDED to do something.

I ended up pulling the groovy code into a java class and then referenced it in the service.

Service code:

```
    static class FileNetService {
         FilenetUtils fu = new FilenetUtils();
         // methods
    }
```

FilenetUtils:

import groovyx.net.ws.WSClient;

import org.grails.plugins.wsclient.service.WebService;

```
public class FilenetUtils {
    WebService webService = new WebService();

    private static groovyx.net.ws.WSClient itgWebService = null; 
    private static groovyx.net.ws.WSClient catWebService = null;

FilenetUtils()  {
        itgWebService = (WSClient) webService.getClient(FILENET_ITG_URL);
        catWebService = (WSClient) webService.getClient(FILENET_CAT_URL);
    }
//More methods, etc.
}
```

It works.  I wanted wiring to work but I just couldn't get it done in time.